# Tk не может закрыться из-за работающего потока threading

Tags: python, tkinter, threading

```
from tkinter import *
import threading as th
isRUNNING = True
def loop():
    global isRUNNING
    while isRUNNING:
        print('loop')
def Exit(event = None):
    print('close!')
    isRUNNING = False
    exit()
thread = th.Thread(target = loop)
thread.start()
FORM = Tk()
FORM.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',Exit)
FORM.mainloop()
```

Мне нужно что-бы по закрытию окна поток останавливался.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `thread = th.Thread(target=loop, daemon=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так можно правильным образом передать сигнал в поток:

```
def loop():
    while not thread.isRUNNING.is_set():
        print('loop')
def Exit(event = None):
    print('close!')
    thread.isRUNNING.set()
    exit()
thread = th.Thread(target = loop)
thread.isRUNNING = threading.Event()
thread.start()
```